# Remote Desktop Connection from Windows to Ubuntu connects, but is a black and white checkerboard screen

Tags: 14.04, xrdp

I need help please, everytime I attempt to connect to my Ubuntu server I do, but it comes up as a black and white checkerboard.

Comment: What RDP server program do you use? Are you using Remote Desktop Connection to connect?

Comment: Yes, Remote Desktop Connection works, I just can't figure out the black and white checkered screen.

Comment: http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305 this helped amazingly. Easy to follow as well.

Comment: I think I know the problem. Does your server have a desktop environment (LXDE, Xfce, Unity, KDE, GNOME, MATE, etc.) or is it just a GUI-less server?

Comment: Assuming you don't have a desktop environment (which 99% of servers do not), I made an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your server does not have a desktop environment installed. In order for xrdp to work, you need to have X (meaning a desktop environment). If you are managing a server, I would not recommend using RDP at all. Instead, use SSH. It is so easy to set up and use that JUST before I wrote this answer, I set up SSH to let me use my Windows 8.1 laptop to connect to my server. It was easy to set up. For information on setting up SSH on the server, go to https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html. Do NOT install the client packages. Then, on your Windows computer, download PuTTY. http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.exe lets you download the main component of PuTTY (the one that lets you send and recieve commands and has a GUI), but also make sure to download PSFTP at http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/psftp.exe. PSFTP is a (simple) tool for transferring files between your Windows computer and your server. I think you'll love it and it is very easy. Also, SSH is much more secure than RDP and much more secure than VNC, so you can be confident knowing your data is safe when managing your server over the internet.